# How to animate both offset axes

Tags: swiftui, offset, axis

How can i animate both `.offset()` axes independently? This looks like a bug right? The blue should keep bouncing up and down but the `y` animation stops once I try to animate the `x` offset.

[image]

```
@State var offsetX = 0.0
@State var offsetY = 0.0
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Color.blue
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .offset(x: offsetX, y: offsetY)
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                    offsetY = 300
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    withAnimation {
                        offsetX = 100
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think it is a bug, it is a limitation. SwiftUI basic animations are hard to sync and even harder to keep synched, background and interruptions really throw everything out of whack. Geometry Effect can be used to create key frame type animations but I still prefer CABasicAnimation for time sensitive animations.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I tried dividing horizontal offset animation to subview and vertical animation to parent view, but it bugs anyway :(

Comment: Upd: posted a hacky workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit overkill, but I made a custom GeometryEffect, and it animates independently:

```
extension View {
  func independentOffset(x: CGFloat = 0, y: CGFloat = 0) -> some View {
    modifier(OffsetGeometryEffect(offset: CGPoint(x: x, y: y)))
  }
}

struct OffsetGeometryEffect: GeometryEffect {
  var offset: CGPoint
  
  var animatableData: CGPoint.AnimatableData {
    get { CGPoint.AnimatableData(offset.x, offset.y) }
    set { offset = CGPoint(x: newValue.first, y: newValue.second) }
  }
  
  func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
    return ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: offset.x, y: offset.y))
  }
}
```